# Why isn't JSX saved as a const rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am fairly new to React & JSX however I was under the impression that you can save JSX as pretty much anything (var,const, let...).

However when I save it as a const and try to render it like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const Test =  <div> hi </div>;

ReactDOM.render((
    <div>
        <Test />
    </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I get the error message:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: object.

And when I replace the test const with the following:

```
const Test = () => { return( <div> hi </div> ) };
```

It renders no problem. Why can't I use the first version?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the first one, but in that case it will be not a React component, it's just a variable referencing the result of creating the `div`, so render it like this:

```
const Test =  <div> hi </div>;

ReactDOM.render((
    <div>
       {Test}          //here
    </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Or, to make it a Stateless Functional Component (SFC), write it as a function returning that `div`:

```
const Test = () => { return( <div> hi </div> ) };
```

Then you can use it as `<Test />`.

Check the **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/introducing-jsx.html)** for more details about JSX.

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to understand this - [look at what the JSX compiles into](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAKgU2jAvDGAeAJgSwG4B8MAFjpgPS6EDcAsAFAMBKCAhsFACIDyAsgHQAnBGCwJBACgkN02fARnpMiZOQX1ZleQwCUAGhhYQwAK4BbEVH4BzBFACiAGwQWwUAEIBPAJJYJAckEQECh_HR1qIA):

```
var Test = React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  ' hi '
);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  React.createElement(Test, null)
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

You're passing an already created instance of an element to the `createElement` function again - instead, you need to just render the existing instance:

```
const test = <div>hi</div>;

ReactDOM.render((
  <div>
    {test}
  </div>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Which compiles to this:](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Creact&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YB4AmBLAbgPgAss0B6bfAbgFgAoWgJXgENgoARAeQFkA6AJ3hgM8PgApRtGOnJ5JUmAG8E0AL5zSM2gEoANDAwhgAVwC2gqDwDm8KAFEANvDNgoAIQCeASQyiA5HxAQKF8tLQogA)

```
var test = React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  'hi'
);

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(
  'div',
  null,
  test
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not create React.Component with

```
  const Test =  <div> hi </div>;
```

So you can not instantiate it with `<Test \>`. If you change the render to

```
 ReactDOM.render((
      <div>
        {Test}
      </div>
    ), document.getElementById('root'));
```

it will work. See the [React guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) for on how to create a React.Component.

Answer (score 0):

`Test` is not a component, so you need to render it with `{Test}` instead of `<Test />`

Comment: I actually wrote it when other answers had yet to be posted, or were posted while I was answering. But I obviously agree with you.